Visual Studio 2022 with tools, SDKs and Frameworks in Docker container
I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to understand if what I'm looking for is possible or not.
Actually, I tried to build a Windows container with VS Build tools inside and the relevant workloads/components that I need for my project.
What I would like to do is to have Visual Studio 2022 as code editor itself, without any additional installation (workload, component, etc.) that uses tools and libraries from inside the container.
As far as I understand, Visual Studio still needs all the relevant components in order to open the solution, even if no debugging/compilation is needed.
What I'm looking for is to have only 1 installation (preferably in a container) for both the container (in order to build the solution and have an isolated environment) and Visual Studio (in order to be able to open the solution).
I created a Windows container and installed vs build tools with the components I need, but I'm not able to let Visual Studio know that the components are there.
